# kql - how to remove all empty strings from an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, kql

Please tell is it possible to remove all empty strings from an array of strings?

```
[
    "",
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24",
    ""
]
```

⟱

```
[
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set_difference()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setdifferencefunction) with the original array and another array with a single empty value.

> Returns a dynamic (JSON) array of the set of all distinct values that are in the first array but aren't in other arrays.

```
let list = dynamic([
    "",
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24",
    ""
]);
let list_empty_items_removed = set_difference(list,dynamic([""]));
print list_empty_items_removed
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| ["Harjumaa","Tallinn","Lastekodu","24"] |

Answer (score 3):

you can use `mv-apply` + `make_list_if()`:

```
datatable(value:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([
        "",
         "Harjumaa",
         "Tallinn",
         "Lastekodu",
         "24",
         ""
    ]), 
]
| mv-apply value on (
    summarize value = make_list_if(value, isnotempty(value))
)
```

| value |
| --- |
| [ "Harjumaa", "Tallinn", "Lastekodu", "24" ] |