# kql - datatable with one cell from an array

Tags: arrays, datatable, kql

How can I create a datatable with one cell from an array?

I have this as an input:

```
let arr = dynamic ([
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24",
    ""
]);
```

This code works:

```
let dt = datatable(value:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([
        "",
         "Harjumaa",
         "Tallinn",
         "Lastekodu",
         "24",
         ""
    ]), 
];
let cleanedArr = dt
| mv-apply value on (
    summarize value = make_list_if(value, isnotempty(value))  
);
print toscalar(cleanedArr);
```

but I need to use `arr` variable as an input

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your start input and end result looks like?

Comment: As an input I have an array of strings. I need to clear it of empty strings. I try to do as as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125362/kql-how-to-remove-all-empty-strings-from-an-array-of-strings/71129474#71129474 but apply expects an array as an input. Thats's why I want to transform my array 'arr' into a datatable.

Comment: Yet another https://xyproblem.info/. `datatable` is for static data and has no relevance to your challenge.  All you needed is `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arr = dynamic ([
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24",
    ""
]);
print source_arr = arr
| mv-apply a = source_arr on (summarize clean_arr = make_list_if(a, isnotempty(a)))
```

---

```
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|                 source_arr                 |                clean_arr                |
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ["Harjumaa","Tallinn","Lastekodu","24",""] | ["Harjumaa","Tallinn","Lastekodu","24"] |
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02NvQoCMRCE+0DeYUmVwNmIndhbWNqJHMvdCutlk5Af4cSH98DjcIph52OW8VQBc4YTjHNA4QHsTStYZM6Yn00QTbeCK3rPIWz5gqXSFMe2kf1hO41Wd3fUKmUOFUpseaD+t7S4Vh+Q1w5T8jPgwv4KMYAtTQQzvwkGTxjWR8GJes+l9vyw2AGXECtJqrNF59wXOF5/GswAAAA=)

Or

```
let arr = dynamic ([
    "Harjumaa",
    "Tallinn",
    "Lastekodu",
    "24",
    ""
]);
print dummy = 0
| mv-apply a = arr on (summarize clean_arr = make_list_if(a, isnotempty(a)))
```

---

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| dummy |                clean_arr                |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
|     0 | ["Harjumaa","Tallinn","Lastekodu","24"] |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAz2OsQoCMRBE%200D%20YbkqgRNE7MTewtJOJCx3EdbL7oUkJ0T8eCPKTTXzGJgJvgCmBEcYqyDTAOaqFTR1J0yPhRG7/g8uGAKJrPmMufhpHpeV7Par7bS62YNWMZEUGBfm2ka2Wr2BnxuMMVTARr7js4DJrYGJXh6G4FHc7xTj5F2gXBzdDfZAWebiOZZq0Fr7ATnid8W%20AAAA)